# Specific numbers and a blank box

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

There are 2 rows of numbers shown below. Which number belongs to the blank box with a question mark? Please choose from the three options stated.

Why were these particular numbers chosen?

[image: A row of five boxes, then space below, then another row of five boxes, then space below, then three answer choices. The first row of boxes has 5 boxes with one number each: "206, 230, 250, 260, 602". The second row of boxes has 5 boxes with one number or symbol each: "2506, 2530, 2550, 2560, ?". The answer choices are: "A: 2902", "B: 2550", and "C:2605".]

Answer (score 5):

*I think @Martund got partway there, but to move my comments on their answer from five months ago into an answer (in the name of closure)...*

The correct answer is:

> **C** - 2605

Why? Note that, as @Martund spotted, the top row of numbers all:

> contain each of the five vowels of the English alphabet exactly once each when written out:
>
>  206 = tw**O** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd s**I**x;
>  230 = tw**O** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd th**I**rty;
>  250 = tw**O** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd f**I**fty;
>  260 = tw**O** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd s**I**xty;
>  602 = s**I**x h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd tw**O**.
>  <sub>*Note that this puzzle requires the use of the linking 'and' between the hundreds and tens/units, as is the convention in [UK English](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2016/08/31/one-thousand-one-hundred-and-ninety-three-how-to-say-numbers-1/).*</sub>

However, what is crucial to the puzzle is to realise that these are:

> **the *first* five numbers to satisfy this pattern.** (See [OEIS A058180](https://oeis.org/A058180))

And that (related) when we look at the bottom row of numbers:

> the given numbers are the first four numbers to contain each of the five vowels of the English alphabet exactly **twice** each when written out:
>
>  2506 = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd f**I**v**E** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd s**I**x;
>  2530 = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd f**I**v**E** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd th**I**rty;
>  2550 = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd f**I**v**E** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd f**I**fty;
>  2560 = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd f**I**v**E** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd s**I**xty.
>
>  i.e. *This* is why the OP chose these particular rows of numbers when setting the puzzle - it isn't arbitrary, and they are not seeking a forced algebraic or manipulation-of-numbers justification for the sequence.

So the next number in this sequence (denoted by the question mark) should be:

> **2605** = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd s**I**x h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd f**I**v**E**. i.e. option **C**.
>
>  Note that neither of the other two options even appear in this sequence:
>  2902 = tw**O** th**OU**s**A**nd n**I**n**E** h**U**ndr**E**d **A**nd tw**O** (3 O's, only 1 I);
>  6052 = s**I**x th**OU**s**A**nd **A**nd f**I**fty tw**O** (no E's, only 1 U).

Answer (score 3):

It is

> A because the difference between bottom and top is 2300.

It is also

> B because the bottom row is obtained by inserting a 5 inside the 2.

Finally, it is

> C because the bottom row is obtained by replacing 2 by 5 and afterwards prepending a 2.

Arguably, the numbers were chosen to

> make the choice between A, B and C ambiguous.

Comment: Ntnva cyrnfr pbafvqre jul jrer gurfr cnegvphyne ahzoref pubfra. V pbhyq unir pubfra nal bgure ahzoref naq nqqrq 2300 be gubfr bgure guvatf

Comment: @DrD not without sacrificing ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The correct option is $B$. Reason is that the numbers in lower table are obtained by appending $5$ beside $2$ in corresponding numbers above. (Another reason one can think is that the last entry in both the tables are obtained by reversing the first entry).

These particular numbers (206, 230, 250, 260, 602) are chosen since these are the numbers whose english names include all the vowels exactly once.
Then we append $5$ particularly, because this the number of vowels in english.

Comment: Please consider the question why were these particular numbers chosen.

Comment: @DrD, you have written that as another part of the question. My answer is partial as of now.

Comment: The problem here is that you need to demonstrate *WHY* your answer is the intended one, *and the other ones are not the intended one* - after all, it is also possible to obtain Answer A simply by adding 2300 to each number in the top row. No doubt there is also a logic that can produce Answer C (which I have not spotted yet). The statement you are dismissing as 'another part of the question' is actually crucial to solving it! :) EDIT: Your new answer now looks more promising!

Comment: @Stiv, I've completed my answer.

Comment: This looks like a more solid answer now, although I have the suspicion the answer the OP is looking for will turn out to be rot13(P, orpnhfr gur ahzoref ba gur obggbz ebj ner nyy ahzoref gung pbagnva rknpgyl GJB BS RNPU IBJRY nsgre nqqvat n '5' gb gur qvtvgf naq zvkvat gurz hc)

Comment: In fact they could just be *the first 5* like the top row...

Comment: @Stiv I apologise in advance for being opinionated, but I kind of don't enjoy the idea of something that far-fetched being allowed to trump the obvious. Besides, it doesn't even [work](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-y-is-sometimes-a-vowel-usage) properly.

Comment: @Stiv your suspicion seems correct (first 5 #'s with 2 of each, presumably), I was about to post that as an answer and then read through all the comments and saw you'd already said as much. Are you going to post an answer so we can close this out, otherwise I guess I can if you don't want to

Comment: @Amoz Hadn't realised this one was still unsolved! I'll write something up shortly, thanks for the prompt :)